# What assertion test case can I write for this program?

Tags: java, spring, testing, sonarqube

I have written 1 assert test case for my Java program. I need to write one more test case for my program to pass Sonarqube test. I am not sure what other assert test case I can write to pass this sonarqube test.

Here is my code for `Tools.java`

```
@Component("Tools")
public class Tools implements Consumer<PMessage> {
    private final OptimisticLockmark<Tble> mark;
    private final giver giver;

    public Tools(
            final OptimisticLockmark<Tble> mark,
            final giver giver) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.giver = giver;
    }


    @Override
    public void accept(PMessage PMessage) {
        LOG.info("ignore "+PMessage.getKey());

    }
}
```

Here is the test case I wrote for this class

```
public class DTest
{
        @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        message = PMessage.builder()
                .ingestedData("Test")
                .key("1")
                .build();
        consumer =
                new Tools(mark,
                        giver);
    }

    @Test
    public void accept()
    {
        consumer.accept(message);
        assertTrue("Pass", true);
    }
}
```

I need some guidance to write one more assert test case to pass sonarqube.

Comment: assertNotNull --?

Comment: @Santos Can you please give me more insight? Thanks

Comment: you can write an assert Statement like assertNotNull(consumer); or the object you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your unit test is complete.  The consumer class you are testing is designed to do nothing apart from generate an "info" log message to say it has done nothing.

Since "do nothing" cannot fail, and it is impractical to test that something has NOT "done nothing", you have tested all that you *could* test.

A pedant might argue that you need to test that the "info" log message is being logged.  However, informational logging is not normally considered to be something that you need to test.